# Starting with databases, Firebase or SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, firebase

So I´m currently developing an App for workouts. I have Objects called Exercises, when I start a workout I fill the exercises with data, for example how many repetitions I did for each exercise. I want to collect all the data and evaluate it later. So that I can draw a diagram about how my repetitions increased over several workouts.

I´m currently saving my workouts and exercises in an ArrayList which serialize and deserialize everytime I start and close my application. It works but I think it would make more sense if I handle all my Objects and data with a database, is that right? However I have never did something with databases before and wondering where I should start. So my 1st Question is, do you know any good beginner tutorials on databases particularly for android?

As far as I understand it, the 2 options I have is to use SQLite or Firebase for my Android Application. My 2nd Question is, which one should I choose? I know SQLite is for locally storing Data. Currently I´m operating locally but I think in the future I want to support saving my data online. So Firebase might be a better choice, however the data should be accessible when there´s no internet connection.

I would appreciate any advice and explains about how databases and which to use. Links to good tutorials would be great too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your 1st Question is concerned, it is a bit open-ended. Do you care about learning a particular Database Management System (DBMS) (e.g., MySQL, Postgres etc)? Or do you care about learning principles of database management systems? If you pick the former, then you have to pick a system, learn its syntax, and adopt it to your App's needs. On the other hand, if you pick the latter, then getting an online course on Principles on Database Management Systems is what you need to do. Personally, I believe that if you follow the first path, you will probably achieve your current goal faster, but in the future you might encounter database-related problems that you won't be able to solve. The latter will take more effort, but it makes more sense if you believe you will have to work with a database in the future.

I don't believe if it's fruitful on my end to provide any links for the following reasons: (i) the Internet is full of online tutorials for different DBMSs, (ii) I don't want to bias you on a particular MOOC that I consider good.

Turning to Question 2, I think you need to first establish your App's scenario. Is the App designed to store data locally, and those are used just by the App? If yes, then an embedded DBMS (like SQLite) is the way to go, since it will be part of your process space, the data will be manageable outside the application if needed, and it can cover all your concurrency/consistency requirements. On the other hand, if your data will be used by an external service as well, then you need a Server-based DBMS service (like Firebase).

I hope my answer helped.

Comment: Thank you very much! At the moment I´m trying to store my Data locally, however in the future, I want my app to save data on a Server for a backup, so when a user deletes the app or switches to another device, the data won't get lost. Also, later on, I want to be able to publish workout programmes and that should work like for example the app store where you automatically get new apps, so I would need some type of server connection aswell. So maybe I need a combination of both, is there something that particularly fits my needs?

Comment: Again, it depends on the architecture and the design goals of your app. I think you can start with an embedded DBMS (i.e., SQLite), and then support remote storage with an external DBMS. By the way, the external DBMS doesn't have to be Firebase necessarily. If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as an answer to your question. Cheers!